# Unknown InvalidCastException in PresentationFramework

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm receiving this weird `InvalidCastException` that does not break at the line where it actually occurs in Debug Mode and does not even tell me what line it is breaking at.

I'm assuming it can't tell me the line because it occurred in the presentation framework. I've compared previous code that worked with my current set and there is nothing that stands out so I'm assuming my designer did some spiffy XAML that is incorrect.

Is there any way to locate the exception without going through hundreds of thousands of lines of markup?

Comment: What is the exception detail?

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.NamedObject' to type 'System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate'.

Comment: are you using any `TemplateSelector`?

Comment: Nope, solution has no template selector.

Comment: Search for any XAML using `DataTemplate` or `ControlTemplate`.

Comment: I know for a fact there are hundreds of both.

Comment: You will have to provide more information. Take a look at [WPF Tracing](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/habibh/archive/2009/07/09/debugging-wpf-applications-in-visual-studio-2010-using-wpf-tracing.aspx)

Comment: Enabled Error mode for WPF tracing but didn't give any other details. I'm at a loss, other than providing an entire solution which I can't do.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to see where these exceptions are coming from is set the debugger to stop on that particular type of exception. In the top menu: **Debug->Exceptions**. Then find the InvalidCastException and check the box.

Run you program again and it will stop and show you the exception box. Make sure you dive into the exception to the inner most exception that was thrown to know what the root cause is.

Comment: This was already set. There is no innerexception, and breaks on window.ShowDialog();